# Sending email on behalf of user via SMTP?

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid, mandrill, mailgun

I'm building an app to allow my users to send email.  I want the email to originate from their domain.   Currently, email is sent on behalf of my Mandrill account with their name/email used for the From header.  It "works" but most of the mail is not delivering as best as I think it could.

The way I see it, one option is to use a service like Mandrill, Mailgun, Sendgrid, etc and have my users update there TXT records to verify their domains, thus allowing me to send on behalf of my users.  Is that correct?

I'm wondering if another option would be to collect SMTP credentials, and then send the message via SMTP for my user, thereby preventing my user from having to log in and update their TXT records before using my app to send messages.  I think it would be far easier to simply add SMTP credentials.  Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not convinced you are on a sane path. If this is programming-related at all, it seems much too broad, and there seem to be some misconceptions about how SMTP works. There is no way in the general case for your software to genuinely send email from outside a user's network and make it appear to come from the inside. Which actual problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: By TXT you probably refer to SPF, but that is really only part of the problem here. Also, many users will not be in complete control of their DNS (though perhaps you only target those who are?)

Comment: No admin anywhere will want you to know their users' credentials, that much is for sure. A possible workaround might be to give your users software they can run on their own computer with their own credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The way I see it, one option is to use a service like Mandrill, Mailgun, Sendgrid, etc and have my users update there TXT records to verify their domains, thus allowing me to send on behalf of my users. Is that correct?"

Correct you'll want them to minimally have an SPF record that says the service you use is allowed to send email for the domain. I.e. TXT v=spf1 +a +mx inlcude:sendgrid.net ~all

"I'm wondering if another option would be to collect SMTP credentials, and then send the message via SMTP for my user, thereby preventing my user from having to log in and update their TXT records before using my app to send messages. I think it would be far easier to simply add SMTP credentials. Is this possible?"

Not really. They'll need to make sure their DNS records minimally have a valid SPF (TXT) record, otherwise the major email providers and players will either drop their messages or mark them as SPAM/junk.